# check for specific key and value pairs in two dictionaries (both dictionary has same key and value pairs)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that have the same key and value pairs. I want to compare only the specific key-value pairs and return true. 
I am new to python, Please help me to write a function for the same.

The dictionaries are

```
A: {'id1': 'target', 'start1': '39', 'end1': '45', \
    'id2': 'query', 'start2': '98', 'end2': '104'}
B: {'id1': 'target', 'start1': '39', 'end1': '45', \
    'id2': 'query', 'start2': '98', 'end2': '104'}
```

Here I want to check if the `'start1'`, `'end1'`, `'start2'` and `'end2'` values are the same are not.

Comment: What about `A[start1] == A[end1] == A[start2] == A[end2] == B[start1] == B[start2] == B[end1] == B[end2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = all( A[k]==B[k] for k in ('start1', 'end1', 'start2', 'end2'))
```

Comment: Thank you!! Also, I have one more doubt. The dict A has no values in 1st iteration. I then assign some values Only in the second iteration then it gets the same value as dict B. How do I compare the second iteration values of dict A and dict B

Comment: Iteration… of what? We cannot guess the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop:

```
wanted_keys = {'start1', 'end1', 'start2', 'end2'}

same = True
for k in wanted_keys:
    if A.get(k) != B.get(k):
        same = False
        break
```

one line code:

```
all(A.get(k) == B.get(k) for k in wanted_keys)
```